# Inconsistent Timing on FinancialBond valuations

Tags: finance, timing

I need to do bond valuations (lots of them across lots of data) using `FinancialBond`.

**Context & Background**

I have daily interest rate data on 30 year US Treasury bonds from 1977 through the present.  Each data element looks like this:

```
{{1977, 2, 15, 0, 0, 0.},0.077}
```

A `DateList` and interest rate.

Given a starting date (e.g., `{1977, 2, 15, 0, 0, 0.}`) I assume a 30 year maturity from the starting date.

At a future date, but prior to the assumed maturity date, I (1) find the interest rate associated with that future date and (2) calculate the "Settlement" value (essentially a proportion of the projected maturity date) like this...

```
maturityDate = DatePlus[{1977, 2, 15, 0, 0, 0.}, {30, "Years"}];
settlement = 30 - DateDifference[{1979, 2, 20, 0, 0, 0.}, maturityDate,"Years"]
        
2.0137
```

**Then things begin to get odd...**

Can anyone provide an explanation of the following?

[image]

The 3rd function takes over 36 seconds to run.
The 4th crashes the kernel.

Code so anyone can replicate the problem.

```
Timing[FinancialBond[{"FaceValue" -> 1000, "Coupon" -> 0.077, 
   "Maturity" -> 30,"CouponInterval" -> 1/2}, {"InterestRate" -> 0.0902, 
   "Settlement" -> 2}]]

Timing[FinancialBond[{"FaceValue" -> 1000, "Coupon" -> 0.077, 
   "Maturity" -> 30,"CouponInterval" -> 1/2}, {"InterestRate" -> 0.0902, 
   "Settlement" -> 2.25}]]

Timing[FinancialBond[{"FaceValue" -> 1000, "Coupon" -> 0.077, 
   "Maturity" -> 30,"CouponInterval" -> 1/2}, {"InterestRate" -> 0.0902, 
   "Settlement" -> 2.0137}]]

Timing[FinancialBond[{"FaceValue" -> 1000, "Coupon" -> 0.077, 
   "Maturity" -> 30,"CouponInterval" -> 1/2}, {"InterestRate" -> 0.0902, 
   "Settlement" -> 2.01}]]
```

It appears that FinancialBond doesn't like certain fractions of a year (e.g., 2.0137 or 2.01).

Thoughts appreciated.

Comment: In a current debugging kernel I am getting an out-of-memory exception as a result. Granted, that's better than a kernel crash. But still bad. I'll poke it a bit more and see what shows up.

Comment: Filing a bug report for this.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau - Many thanks for continuing to improve the platform.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the examples in the documentation for [`FinancialBond`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FinancialBond.html), you can see that the parameters are almost always provided as [exact numbers](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/18485#18485). This hints that for certain numeric parameters, some numerical errors probably accumulate and lead to memory overflow.

A simple solution is to use only exact numbers.

```
Timing[FinancialBond[{"FaceValue" -> 1000, "Coupon" -> 0.077, 
 "Maturity" -> 30, 
 "CouponInterval" -> 1/2}, {"InterestRate" -> 0.0902, 
 "Settlement" -> Rationalize[2.01]}]]

(* {0.0625, 866.027} *)
```

---

Otherwise, I don't know much about finances and what this function actually does. But you can try diving into the source code yourself with

```
GeneralUtilities`PrintDefinitions[FinancialBond]
```

and debug the issue. Probably, there is some "while-like" loop that never finishes due to numerical errors.

Comment: Good workaround. Thx.